# Как синхронизировать сразу несколько объектов?

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Один объект синхронизировать? Да пожалуйста!

```
Object object = new Object();
synchronized(object) {
    // действия с ним
}
```

А, вот, как синхронизировать некоторый список объектов? Не писать же множество вложенных друг в друга `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете синхронизировать один объект за раз. Если вам надо синхронизировать несколько, вам придется писать вложенные блоки. Но я бы не рекомендовал так делать - если у вас много вложенных блоков, то вы, вероятно, что то делаете не так.

Как пример, пусть будет класс

```
static class MySyncDemo{
    private Object[] myArray = new Object[] {new Object()};

    public void RunArraySynced() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (myArray){
            while (true){
                System.out.println("RunArraySynced");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RunObjectSynced() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (myArray[0]){
            while (true){
                System.out.println("RunObjectSynced");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Попробуем его вызвать параллельно

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    MySyncDemo demo = new MySyncDemo();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
        try {
            demo.RunArraySynced();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
        try {
            demo.RunObjectSynced();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    obj.readLine();

    t1.interrupt();
    t2.interrupt();
}
```

На выходе получим

```
RunArraySynced
RunObjectSynced
RunArraySynced
RunObjectSynced
RunObjectSynced
RunArraySynced
RunObjectSynced
RunArraySynced
```

Что показывает, что синхронизация массива не синхронизирует элементы массива.

Тем более в java doc в отрывке, где рассказывают про блок synchronized, говорят только о объектах, о массивах там ни слова: [ссылка на этот отрывок](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

В действительности, для защиты массива от одновременного доступа, нет никакой необходимости синхронизироваться на массиве. Нужно только синхронизировать операции над массивом.

Рассмотрим следующий класс

```
public class SynchronizedArray<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> _innerArray;
    private Object _syncObject = new Object();

    public SynchronizedArray(int capacity) {
        _innerArray = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
    }

    public void AddItem(int index, T item) {
        synchronized (_syncObject) {
            _innerArray.add(index, item);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int index) {
        synchronized (_syncObject) {
            _innerArray.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Что мы видим:

1. Это отдельный класс, который предоставляет доступ к приватному полю массива. Никто, кроме этого класса, доступа к массиву не имеет. Таким образом, мы полностью контролируем все операции над массивом.
2. Для синхронизации выбран отдельный объект - и для этого есть ряд причин:

   - Мы не можем для синхронизации использовать массив, так как массив - это семантически просто данные класса, ответственность массива - хранить данные. Массив может быть в любое время пересоздан, но операции по прежнему должны быть синхронизированы.
   - Мы не можем использовать для синхронизации this, так как это ссылка на сам объект-обертку, которая доступна внешнему миру. То есть вызывающий код может попробовать сделать где-то у себя следующее:

```
    SynchronizedArray<Integer> array = new SynchronizedArray<>(10);
    synchronized (array){
        ....
    }
```

То есть при синхронизации на this надо иметь ввиду, что вызывающий код может быть также на нем синхронизирован.  Чтобы уменьшить эту сложность и избежать потенциальных проблем с взаимоблокировкой потоков, я создал в классе приватное поле `private Object _syncObject = new Object();`, на котором может синхронизироваться только наш класс и больше никуда это поле не доступно.

Подобный подход предоставляет возможность использовать несколькими потоками структуры данных, что не предназначены для работы в многопоточном окружении.

Это самый простой и топорный способ, в реальности зачастую операции над объектами поддерживают разную степерь конкурентности. Например, можно безопасно читать элементы массива многопоточно, но вот запись в массив должна быть однопоточная. В таким случае используют [более продвинутые блокировки](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-locks) (например, ReaderWriterLock)

ps. Я не спец по java, сам ещё учу её, так что тыкание пальцем в ошибки приветствуется.

Comment: Только, вот, не понятно, зачем они вообще разрешили класть туда ссылку на массив объектов.

Comment: По сути туда дается любая ссылка типа Object. По любой из них можно синхронизироваться. Массив также наследуется от Object, потому его тоже можно использовать. Но так на практике не делают, обычно для синхронизации создают специальный объект.

Comment: Хмм, а вот спец объект, содержащий поля, которые нужно синхронизировать, это интересно. Добавьте, пожалуйста, это в ответ.

Comment: Сейчас убегаю, как вернусь - добавлю

Comment: Кстати, не стоит забывать о синхронизированных методах. Тоже должны очень помогать в таких случаях

Comment: Добавил немного инфы. Но имейте ввиду, что я сам на C# пишу, потому в каких то деталях могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 3):

Синхронизировать мы можете не объекты, а потоки. Объект, который вы используете в блоке `synchronized`, используется для захвата так называемого монитора в нём. Только один поток может захватить и удерживать монитор в данный момент времени. Остальные потоки, пытающиеся это сделать, входят в режим ожидания. Монитор объекта освобождается после выхода из блока `synchronized` или даже раньше - после запуска одного из вариантов метода `wait()` внутри этого блока. Синхронизированный метод это более краткая форма записи обычного метода, весь код которого находится в блоке `synchronized`. При этом объектом синхронизации становится `this`, если метод обычный, либо данный класс, если метод статический.

Вы можете, если вам это действительно необходимо, синхронизировать потоки несколькими объектами, но в этом случае важно в каком порядке вы это делаете. Если порядок захвата и освобождения мониторов у нескольких объектов будет неодинаков, легко попасть в состояние взаимной блокировки или дедлока.

Comment: ага, то есть, блокируя монитор массива, мы не блокируем мониторы элементов массива?

Comment: @Miron Да, элементы массива - это другие объекты или даже примитивы, такие как `int`.

Comment: То есть, когда я пишу synchronized(this), я блокирую мониторы у всех объектов, фигурирующих в его(synchronized-а) теле?

Comment: @Miron Нет, только у самого `this`.

Comment: То есть, запрещаю другим потокам от того же класса входить в данный конкретный блок? Так же, получается, и с синхронизированными методами?

Comment: @Miron Запрещаете любым другим потокам захватывать монитор этого одного объекта, пока данный поток его не освободил.

Comment: Я про блок synchronized(this)